# SQL: Add missing dates and values

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

Hello and first time poster! :)

I have a table which outputs this example data, but for many users and different date ranges:-

```
Users..........Date..............Hours
John Smith.....Thu 02-JAN-2020...8 
John Smith.....Fri 03-JAN-2020...8 
John Smith.....Mon 06-JAN-2020...8 
John Smith.....Tue 07-JAN-2020...8 
John Doe.......Fri 03-JAN-2020...8
John Doe.......Mon 06-JAN-2020...8 
John Doe.......Tue 07-JAN-2020...8 
John Doe.......Wed 08-JAN-2020...8
```

Result should read:-
Users.............Date........................Hours 
John Smith.....Thu 02-JAN-2020...8 
John Smith.....Fri 03-JAN-2020...8 
John Smith.....Sat 04-JAN-2020...0 MISSING WEEKEND 
John Smith.....Sun 05-JAN-2020...0 MISSING WEEKEND 
John Smith.....Mon 06-JAN-2020...8 
John Smith.....Tue 07-JAN-2020...8 
John Doe.......Fri 03-JAN-2020...8 
John Doe.......Sat 04-JAN-2020...0 MISSING WEEKEND 
John Doe.......Sun 05-JAN-2020...0 MISSING WEEKEND 
John Doe.......Mon 06-JAN-2020...8 
John Doe.......Tue 07-JAN-2020...8 
John Doe.......Wed 08-JAN-2020...8

I require a query to include the missing weekends, Name and Hours of zero (as DBA will not change the structure of the table and add the weekends).

Have looked at CTE's (Recursives), CROSS JOINS, linking a calendar table, but cannot get this to work.

Any advice or pointers greatly received.

Many thanks.

P.S. Still getting used to formatting, apologies.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  What does "missing weekends" mean?  And tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Pleas tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: I had tagged sql to the end of the post

Comment: @SqlRookie . . . SQL is a language, not a database.  Every database has its own dialect, which is important to answer your question so it is most useful to you.

Comment: Did you use a left outer join when attempting the calendar table? I can't imagine how that could have failed you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `union all` to find Fridays where the user has another date.  Then add two more rows.

I am going to assume that the `date` column actually has a `date` data type.

Here is the idea:

```
select user, date, hours
from t
union all
select user, dateadd(day, v.n, date), 0
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by user order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t cross join
     (values (1), (2)) v(n)
where datepart(weekday, t.date) = 'Friday' and
      next_date is not null;
```

Date/time functions are notoriously database-dependent.  This uses SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 0):

How can i add missing dates in below query..

$
select u.NAME,u.BADGENUMBER, attendance.SENSORID, attendance.CHECKDate, attendance.CheckIn ,attendance.CheckOut
,cast(DATEDIFF(n, attendance.CheckIn, attendance.checkout) / 60 as varchar) + ':' + cast(DATEDIFF(n, attendance.CheckIn, attendance.checkout) % 60 as varchar) as Minutes
from (
select temp.USERID, temp.SENSORID, temp.CHECKDate ,temp.CheckIn
,case when temp.COut = temp.CheckIn then null when temp.CheckIn is null then null else temp.COut end as CheckOut
from(
select c.USERID, c.SENSORID, convert(date, CHECKTIME) CHECKDate
--,(select temp.USERID, dateadd(day,1, CHECKTIME cinout where temp.USERID = c.USERID)) CHEC2
,(select min(CHECKTIME) from CHECKINOUT cinout where cinout.USERID = c.USERID and cinout.SENSORID = c.SENSORID and cinout.CheckTime >= dateadd(hour, 6, convert(datetime, convert(date, c.CheckTime)))) CheckIn
,(select max(CHECKTIME) from CHECKINOUT cinout where cinout.USERID = c.USERID and cinout.SENSORID = c.SENSORID and cinout.CheckTime <= dateadd(hour, 29, convert(datetime, convert(date, c.CheckTime)))) COut
from CHECKINOUT c
group by c.USERID, c.SENSORID, convert(date, CHECKTIME), datename(DW,checktime)
)temp
) attendance
inner join  userinfo u on u.USERID = attendance.userid where u.USERID = 77
$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33294965)